# Change the Color of specific substrings in NSTextView

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsstring, nstextview

I want to change the color of specific text in NSTextView. The method should check that after a keydown event.

For example: the word void is finished and the string void changes the
color to blue. Like a code editor.

I searched for a long time but don't find anything.
My Code:

```
 NSRange range = [text rangeOfString:@"void"];
 NSString *substring = [[text substringFromIndex:NSMaxRange(range)] stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];
 //I think, here is the mistake.
 NSAttributedString *now = [NSAttributedString initWithString:substring];
 [now setTextColor:[[NSColor blueColor]]];
```

I have read that i have to use a `NSAttributedString` but i don't know how I can get this class from a string.

I'am quite new in cocoa programming.

Thanks for every help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this way:

```
NSString *str = @"Hello. That is a test attributed string.";

//in place of NSMakeRange put your range

[self.textview setRichText:YES];
[self.textview setString:str];
[self.textview setTextColor:[NSColor redColor] range:NSMakeRange(3,5)];
```

Comment: How can i set this in a NSTextView?

Comment: [textView setRichText:YES]; and try [textView setAttributedString:str];

Comment: Its call "'NSTextView' may not respond to 'setAttributedString:'".

Comment: Ahh i have fixed it with: [[codrTextView textStorage] setAttributedString: str];. But now i have the problem that the whole textview color and background is set.

Comment: thats quite cool. Have a try with my answer... and say if you want more :)

Comment: Thats the code: NSString *text = [codrTextView string];
    
    NSRange range = [text rangeOfString:@"void"];
    NSString *substring = [[text substringFromIndex:NSMaxRange(range)] stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];
    
    [self.codrTextView setRichText:YES];
    [self.codrTextView setString:substring];
    [self.codrTextView setTextColor:[NSColor redColor] range:range];

Comment: Ohh f*** sorry. Can't create a new question... I have insert your code but now, if i click the button it deletes the whole text.

Comment: Ahh now i find the mistake

Comment: [self.codrTextView setString:text];, i have added the substring. Tons of thanks for the help. Made my day :D

Comment: Ohhh thank god.... as i checked your code, i thoght what you tried.... Any wayz best of luck for your future coding :)